# How can I get the SearcIDs of different searchNames using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can anyone help me sort this is problem out? I'd like to get the id of a searchName each time  user checks the checkbox. I actually want to pass the value of this php line $search_row->searchid to the id in the input if possible. Sorry if my question is wrongly asked. Please help!!!

```
<li class="treeview">           
    <a href="#">
        <i class="active fa fa-search"></i> 
        <span>Searches</span> 
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>    
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick='selectAll(this.checked)'> 
            <span style="color: #fff; ">SELECT ALL</span>
        </li>
        <?php foreach ($query as $search_row){ ?>
            <li style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="searchid" onclick="getSearchId()" name="searchName"> 
                <span style="color: #fff; ">
                    <?php echo $search_row->searchname;?> 
                    <?php echo '<br>';?>
                    <?php $search_row->searchid ;?>
                    <span>
            </li> 
        <?php }?>         
    </ul>
</li>
```

```js
function getSearchId(){
    var checkedValues = "";
    var count = 0;

    checkedValues = $('#searchid:checked').map(function () {
        count = count + 1;
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");

    localStorage.setItem("#searchid", checkedValues);
    alert(checkedValues);
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid as you'll have multiple elements with the id of `searchid`. `id` attributes *must* be unique within a document. If you want to group elements, use a class

Comment: What does *"id of searchName"* mean? What are expected results?

Comment: Are you trying to store the checked value and associate it to the input id in localstorage? At least that's what it seems you're trying to do.

Comment: @Goliadkin yes I'm trying to store the checked value and associate it to the input id

Comment: `How can I get the SearcIDs of different searchNames` this title is really confusing. What are `SearchIds` for you and what is `searchNames`?

Comment: Please try to reduce your problem into smallest form still fully covering your problem. For example, probably css classes and php are not relevant. It might happen you'll find solution yourself while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique, you should use class instead

PHP

```
<?php foreach ($query as $search_row){ ?>
  <li style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="searchid" onclick="getSearchId()" name="searchName" /> 
     ...
  </li> 
<?php }?>
```

JS

```
...
checkedValues = $('.searchid:checked').map(function () {
  count = count + 1;
  return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```